# How to use re.sub(), or similar, to do replacements and generate raw strings without the metacharacters causing problems with the regex engine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-negation

```py
import re

personal_pronoun = "se les"   #example 1
personal_pronoun = "se le"    #example 2
personal_pronoun = "se   le"  #example 3
personal_pronoun = "les"      #example 4
personal_pronoun = "le"       #example 5

#re.match() only matches at the beginning of the string
if re.match(r"se", personal_pronoun): 
    #concatenate this regex "negative look behind" to make a conditional negative match
    personal_pronoun_for_regex = re.sub(r"^se", r"(?<!se\s)se", personal_pronoun)
else: 
    personal_pronoun_for_regex = personal_pronoun

#re.search() searches for matches anywhere in the string.
if re.search(r"\s*le$", personal_pronoun_for_regex): 
    #concatenate the \b metacharacter representing a word boundary
    personal_pronoun_for_regex = re.sub(r"le$", r"le\b", personal_pronoun_for_regex)

#I check how the raw string looks like before using it in a regex
print(repr(personal_pronoun_for_regex)) # --> output raw string
```

This code give me that error `raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this)) re.error: bad escape \s at position 6`

What could I do to get these raw strings into the `personal_pronoun_for_regex` variable without having these `re` errors?

I think this is because there is an error within the `re.sub()` functions, causing a `re.error` object to be raised indicating that there was a problem processing the replacing regular expression.

This is how the raw string, so that special characters are interpreted literally as part of the regular expression, should actually look like:

```py
personal_pronoun_for_regex = r"se les"           #for example 1
personal_pronoun_for_regex = r"se le\b"          #for example 2
personal_pronoun_for_regex = r"se   le\b"        #for example 3
personal_pronoun_for_regex = r"(?<!se\s)les"     #for example 4
personal_pronoun_for_regex = r"(?<!se\s)le\b"    #for example 5
```

Comment: I told you to use `.replace('\\', '\\\\')`, didn't it work? Just double the backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to do that, but the problem is that in the end it is necessary that the raw strings remain as they are indicated in the output of the question, if I do eo I would then have to do a deletion of consecutive characters

Comment: The result will be exactly what you need. If you need the original string, use the right variable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Soory, but I think this question was closed too quickly, I even managed to answer the comment you made

Comment: No, it is all fine. You must do what I said.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew should i remove the raw string format `r` before doing that? In this lines like this:  `personal_pronoun_for_regex = re.sub(r"^se", "(?<!se\\s)se", personal_pronoun)` and like this `personal_pronoun_for_regex = re.sub(r"le$", r"le\\b", personal_pronoun_for_regex)`

Comment: As I said, use double backslashes to insert one backslash, it is the third time I repeat it. BUT: this is a general solution. In your code, all you need is `startswith` and `endswith`: https://ideone.com/kulwUu

Comment: And stop using `repr(...)` - no idea how many times I repeated it. It confuses you and everyone. Regex is **text**. You must know the exact regex **text** to know what it matches. String literals are for the code, let Python read them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use repr only for testing, as it helps me decide if I need to use a .strip() or if there are \n or \t line breaks in between

Comment: And then you suddenly copy the string literal and start using it as a real text and then make more mistakes... Anyway, you can use anything in your code, but on SO, it will confuse a lot of users who would want to try and help you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I try with your code, but this give me a wrong output, check this https://www.online-python.com/ad9rOim5xJ

Comment: I get a this `le\b` and not this `(?<!se\s)le\b`

Comment: That is because `le` does not start with `se`. Please check your logic.